# Flutter/Dart - getting StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> to rebuild child when value changes

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get a specific icon to appear based on whether the user has taken the survey or not.

At the moment, I am using StreamBuilder to listen for a given value in a document, which returns the survey name. I then want to use the survey name in the next StreamBuilder, which will look in a given collection (which is made up of the survey name followed by _entrants - so, for example, Survey_entrants) for a completed survey document, which will have the title of the user's unique id (named userid).

The problem I have now is that whilst surveyName does return the name of the survey put in Cloud Firestore, and updates it when I change the value (I can see this by the commented-out return new Text('$surveyName'); command).

However, it does not seem to be passing that value into the next StreamBuilder - regardless of what I put in as the survey name, I get the check icon showing, suggesting (snapshot1.hasData) - even when that document does not exist.

I know the surveyName variable is working, but if I do snapshot1.toString() I get the error Snapshot(ConnectionState.active, Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', null). This must count has having data, hence showing the survey being taken. How do I correct this?

My code:

```
Positioned(
  right: 30,
  top: 20,
  child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance
    .collection('Controller')
    .document('Current Survey')
    .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else {
        var sn = snapshot.data;
        surveyName = sn["cs"];
//      return new Text('$surveyName');
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('$surveyName' + '_entrants')
          .document(userid)
          .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot1) {
            if (!snapshot1.hasData) {
              return Icon(
                Foundation.burst_new,
                size: 48,
                color: Color(0xff303841),
              );
            } else if (snapshot1.hasData) {
              return Icon(
                Foundation.check,
                size: 48,
                color: Color(0xff303841),
              );
            } else {
              return Icon(
                MaterialIcons.error_outline,
                size: 48,
                color: Color(0xff303841),
              );
            }
          });
      }
    })),
```

My Cloud Firestore database looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT6nJ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was that Cloud Firestore returns a DocumentSnapshot even when there is nothing in the database to return. So, I changed `(snapshot1.hasData)` to `(snapshot1.data.exists)` and this works as expected - the icon changes based on the response.

```
                    Positioned(
                        right: 45,
                        top: 15,
                        child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                            stream: Firestore.instance
                                .collection('Controller')
                                .document('Current Survey')
                                .snapshots(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                              } else {
                                var sn = snapshot.data;
                                surveyName = sn["cs"];
//                                return new Text('$surveyName');
                                return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                                    stream: Firestore.instance
                                        .collection(surveyName + '_entrants')
                                        .document(userid)
                                        .snapshots(),
                                    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot1) {
                                      if (!snapshot1.data.exists) {
                                        return Icon(
                                          Foundation.burst_new,
                                          size: 36,
                                          color: Color(0xff303841),
                                        );
                                      } else if (snapshot1.data.exists) {
//                                        return Text(snapshot.toString(),
//                                            overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
//                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8));
                                        return Icon(
                                          Foundation.check,
                                          size: 36,
                                          color: Color(0xff303841),
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        return Icon(
                                          MaterialIcons.error_outline,
                                          size: 36,
                                          color: Color(0xff303841),
                                        );
                                      }
                                    });
                              }
                            })),
```